# How can I monitor the user downloading crucial data of company (e.g customer list) using FairWarning app in Salesforce?

Tags: sales-cloud

I have installed `FairWarning` App through AppExchange. How can I track the user(s) who download/export the company's crucial data, say, Customer list using `FairWarning` App?

Answer (score 1):

That app leverages the event monitoring addon from SF, this has been upgraded as of Summer 16 release to include the Admin Analytics Wave dashboards.

You can track who is downloading the customer list using the wave dashboard alone. Also, you can take an additional step and start to leverage the Transaction Security functionality included in Event Monitoring to prevent the download of customer data (or alert an admin) in real time, as opposed to waiting 24 hours for the result.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_overview_transactions.htm

Comment: Thanx Adam..I will be more happy to know that How can I get Event monitoring addon for Salesforce, so that I can use FairWarning App. Or do I need to install another app for Event Monitoring addon?? Please help me with this too.